# Inequalities with DateObjects

Tags: date-and-time

Here the simplest example of this kind of bug

```
In[16]:= Now > Now
During evaluation of In[16]:= Greater::nordol: Mon 11 Sep 2017 18:23:39GMT+2. and Mon 11 Sep 2017 18:23:39GMT+2. cannot be compared because they are overlapping.
Out[16]= DateObject[{2017, 9, 11, 18, 23, 39.0091}, "Instant","Gregorian", 2.] >DateObject[{2017, 9, 11, 18, 23, 39.0091},"Instant","Gregorian", 2.]
```

Same error if we pause for less than 1 second like

```
Now>(Pause[0.2];Now)
```

The inequality does not return an error only if we pause for more than one second. 
I tried on two different laptops with OS Fedora 25 and 26 respectevely, Mathematica version 11.1.
On the other hand, the mathematica-online version of this inequality correctly return False.

**EDIT** 1

A workaround I've found

```
NumericalOrder[Now, Now] == 1

True
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until the behavior has been confirmed by other users.

Comment: The Cloud version is running version 11.2, which will be released for the desktop soon. So it seems any untoward behavior in 11.1 has been fixed there.

Comment: So how to sort two dateobjects (or timeobjects) that are less than one second apart in time? Given two files, I need to compare  FileDate@"file1" with FileDate@"file2" or to compare it with Now; I would like a solution that works regardless of the time interval spanning between the mentioned objects. Thank You.